# Não estou entendendo porque meu programa não está funcionado

Tags: python

Eu estava criando um programa que definia qual era a maior idade entre 4 pessoas caso ela fosse Masculina, até em então consegui fazer os códigos que definem quem é mais velho mas quando tento definir que a pessoa tem que ser do sexo "M" Masculino o programa simplesmente me da 0 como resposta, isso só ocorre quando eu adiciono os seguintes comandos
(and a2 == "M":, and b2 == "M":, and c2 == "M", and d2 == "M":). Eu estou aprendendo a programar em python

```
    a = str(input("Insira seu nome: "))
    a1 = int(input("Insira a sua idade: "))
    a2 = str(input("Informe seu sexo [M/F]: ")).upper()
    print(" ")
    b = str(input("Insira seu nome: "))
    b1 = int(input("Insira a sua idade: "))
    b2 = str(input("Informe seu sexo [M/F]: ")).upper()
    print(" ")
    c = str(input("Insira seu nome: "))
    c1 = int(input("Insira a sua idade: "))
    c2 = str(input("Informe seu sexo [M/F]: ")).upper()
    print(" ")
    d = str(input("Insira seu nome: "))
    d1 = int(input("Insira a sua idade: "))
    d2 = str(input("Informe seu sexo [M/F]: ")).upper()
    
    maior_idade_homem = 0
    if a1 > b1 and a1 > c1 and a1 > d1 and a2 == "M":
        maior_idade_homem = a
    elif b1 > a1 and b1 > c1 and b1 > d1 and b2 == "M":
        maior_idade_homem = b
    elif c1 > a1 and c1 > b1 and c1 > d1 and c2 == "M":
        maior_idade_homem = c
    elif d1 > a1 and d1 > c1 and b1 > c1 and d2 == "M":
        maior_idade_homem = d
    print("O homem da maior idade é {}".format(maior_idade_homem))
```

Comment: Por que na primeira vez que solicitou o sexo você usou `upper()` e nas outras vezes fez apenas `upper`, sem os parenteses?

Comment: Vale lembrar que `input` retorna uma string, então fazer `str(input(...))` é desnecessário, use apenas o `input(...)` e pronto, já terá a string.

Comment: Como citado anteriormente: coloque `upper()`. Outra coisa, seu último `if` que está assim `elif d1 > a1 and d1 > c1 and d1 > c1 and d2 == "M":`... Creio que deveria ser `elif d1 > a1 and d1 > b1 and d1 > c1 and d2 == "M":`. Perceba que vc usou `d1 > c1` duas vezes.

Comment: Aqueles parêneses estão errados mesmo Woss, vlw por avisar

Comment: okay hkotsubo, vlw pelo lembrete

Comment: Verifiquei aqui Paulo Marques e realmente estava errado, já corrigi mas o código continua dando 0 como resultado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue o código "funcional":

```
a = input("Insira seu nome: ")
a1 = int(input("Insira a sua idade: "))
a2 = input("Informe seu sexo [M/F]: ").upper()
print(" ")
b = input("Insira seu nome: ")
b1 = int(input("Insira a sua idade: "))
b2 = input("Informe seu sexo [M/F]: ").upper()
print(" ")
c = input("Insira seu nome: ")
c1 = int(input("Insira a sua idade: "))
c2 = input("Informe seu sexo [M/F]: ").upper()
print(" ")
d = input("Insira seu nome: ")
d1 = int(input("Insira a sua idade: "))
d2 = input("Informe seu sexo [M/F]: ").upper()

maior_idade_homem = 0
if a1 >= b1 and a1 >= c1 and a1 >= d1 and a2 == "M":
    maior_idade_homem = a
elif b1 >= a1 and b1 >= c1 and b1 >= d1 and b2 == "M":
    maior_idade_homem = b
elif c1 >= a1 and c1 >= b1 and c1 >= d1 and c2 == "M":
    maior_idade_homem = c
elif d1 >= a1 and d1 >= b1 and d1 >= c1 and d2 == "M":
    maior_idade_homem = d
print("O homem da maior idade é {}".format(maior_idade_homem))
```

O problema do seu código original era no seu último `elif`:

```
elif d1 > a1 and d1 > c1 and b1 > c1 and d2 == "M":
```

Note que na terceira condição deste `elif`, você está verificando se `b1 > c1`, quando na verdade você deveria verificar se `d1 > c1` (muito provavelmente aconteceu por falta de atenção/erro de digitação).

Note que como sugerido por [willer quintanilha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/132304/willer-quintanilha), utilize `>=` pois caso duas ou mais pessoas tiverem a maior idade igual, o seu código retornaria 0, pois não entraria em nenhum `if`.

**Porém**, o seu código ainda há um bug, este de lógica em contraste com o bug de digitação que você teve.

O seu programa vai falhar caso uma pessoa de sexo `F` tiver a maior idade de todas as pessoas. Este bug vou deixar para você resolver, visto que é um ótimo exercício de lógica para você praticar!

Comment: Okay muito obrigado pela ajuda willer quintanilha, vou ver se consigo resolver esse problema de quando a "F" possuir uma maior idade. Obrigado

Comment: Não sou ele, mas fico feliz que tenha te ajudado :P . Caso a resposta tenha correspondido ao que você esperava, você pode aceitar esta resposta clicando no tique na lateral.

Comment: Okay obrigado por avisar ihavenoidea

Answer (score 0):

Olá Gustavo você cometeu um erro nesta linha :

```
  d2 = str(input("Informe seu sexo [M/F]: ")).upper
```

O correto seria:

```
  d2 = str(input("Informe seu sexo [M/F]: ")).upper()
```

Alem disso recomento alterar `>` por `>=` pois em situações onde a idade maior se repete o programa retornara 0

Comment: Eu arrumei isso mas o comando continua dando 0, não sei por quê

Comment: A idade maior foi repetida ?

Comment: Nada é repetido somente aparece "o homem de maior idade é 0" sendo que era para aparecer o nome do homem que possui a maior idade